# In ggplot, how to draw a circle/disk with a line that divides its area according to a given ratio and colored points inside?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I want to visualize proportions using points inside a circle. For example, let's say that I have 100 points that I wish to scatter (somewhat randomly jittered) in a circle.

[image: 100pointsbw]

Next, I want to use this diagram to represent the proportions of people who voted Biden/Harris in 2020 US presidential elections, in each state.

**Example #1 -- Michigan**

Biden got 50.62% of Michigan's votes. I'm going to draw a horizontal diameter that splits the circle to two halves, and then color the points under the diameter in blue (Democrats' color).

[image: michigan]

---

**Example #2 -- Wyoming**

Unlike Michigan, in Wyoming Biden got only 26.55% of the votes, which is approximately a quarter of the vote. In this case I'd draw a horizontal chord that divides the circle such that the *disk*'s area under the chord is 25% of the entire disk area. Then I'll color the respective points in that area in blue. Since I have 100 points in total, 25 points represent the 25% who voted Biden in Wyoming.

[image: wyoming]

---

**My question:** How can I do this with `ggplot`? I researched this issue, and there's a lot of geometry going on here. First, the kind of area I'm talking about is called a "[circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment)". Second, there are many formulas to calculate its area, if we know some other parameters about the shape (such as the radius length, etc.). See [this](https://www.mathopenref.com/segmentareaht.html) nice demo.

However, my goal isn't to solve geometry problems, but just to represent proportions in a very specific way:

1. draw a circle
2. sprinkle X number of points inside
3. draw a (real or invisible) horizontal line that divides the circle/disk area according to a given proportion
4. ensure that the points are arranged respective to the split. That is, if we want to represent a 30%-70% split, then have 30% of the points under the line that divides the disk.
5. color the points under the line.

I understand that this is somewhat an exotic visualization, but I'll be thankful for any help with this.

---

EDIT

---

I've found a reference to a [JavaScript package](https://npm.io/package/divide-up-circle-in-circular-segments) that does something very similar to what I'm asking.

Comment: I understand that your *goal* isn't to solve geometry problems, but I think that's what you'll have to do in order to solve this problem ... what have you tried to get started? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

Comment: I also think that this is a really poor way to visualize proportions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a crack at this for fun. There's a lot more that could be done.  I agree that this is not a great way to visualize proportions, but if it's engaging your audience ...

Formulas for determining appropriate heights are taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment). In particular we need the formulas

```
a/A = (theta - sin(theta))/(2*pi)
h = 1-cos(theta/2)
```

where `a` is the area of the segment; `A` is the whole area of the circle; `theta` is the angle described by the arc that defines the segment (see Wikipedia for pictures); and `h` is the height of the segment.

### Machinery for finding heights.

```r
afun <- function(x) (x-sin(x))/(2*pi)
## curve(afun, from=0, to = 2*pi)
find_a <- function(a) {
    uniroot(
        function(x) afun(x) -a,
        interval=c(0, 2*pi))$root
}
find_h <- function(a) {
    1- cos(find_a(a)/2)
}
vfind_h <- Vectorize(find_h)
## find_a(0.5)
## find_h(0.5)
## curve(vfind_h(x), from = 0, to= 1)
```

### set up a circle

```r
dd <- data.frame(x=0,y=0,r=1)
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_void())
gg0 <- ggplot(dd) + geom_circle(aes(x0=x,y0=y,r=r)) + coord_fixed()
```

### finish

```r
props <- c(0.2,0.5,0.3)  ## proportions
n <- 100                 ## number of points to scatter
cprop <- cumsum(props)[-length(props)]
h <- vfind_h(cprop)
set.seed(101)
r <- runif(n)
th <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)
  
dd <- 
 data.frame(x = sqrt(r) * cos(th), 
            y = sqrt(r) * sin(th))

dd2 <- data.frame(x=r*cos(2*pi*th), y = r*sin(2*pi*th))
dd2$g <- cut(dd2$y, c(1, 1-h, -1))
gg0 + geom_point(data=dd2, aes(x, y, colour = g), size=3)
```

There are a bunch of tweaks that would make this better (meaningful names for the categories; reverse the axis order to match the plot; maybe add segments delimiting the sections, or (more work) polygons so you can shade the sections.

You should **definitely** check this for mistakes — e.g. there are places where I may have used a set of values where I should have used their first differences, or vice versa (values vs cumulative sum). But this should get you started.

[image: circle with points representing proportions]

Comment: Thanks @Ben, this is incredibly helpful. Trying to wrap my head around the code. May I ask for a hint -- where should I modify the code to ensure that the *number* of points in each segment represents the respective proportion? For example, in the plot you generated, the top segment (blue) accounts for 20% of the disc area, yet there are only 8 blue points (rather than 20 of total of 100). If I wanted the number of points in each segment to reflect proportions given in `props` vector, how should I do that?

Comment: I adopted the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68619289/6105259) to deal with the clustering around the center. As a side-effect, the modified code also changed the number of points in each color/segment., bringing it closer to the desired proportions in `props`. Still, as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lORnF.png), this is still not an accurate representation of `props`.
The modified code: 
`r <- runif(n); th <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi); dd2 <- data.frame(x = sqrt(r) * cos(th), y = sqrt(r) * sin(th)`

Comment: Please feel free to edit ...  also, are the inaccuracies just binomial sampling inaccuracies?  Do you get closer to the expected proportions with larger N?

Comment: Yes, I do get more accurate proportions with larger N...