# How to randomly scatter points inside a circle with ggplot, without clustering around the center?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I want to use `ggplot` to draw a circle, then scatter points inside it. I have code ([adopted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68606605/6105259)) that gets me pretty close to what I want. However, I want the points to scatter inside the circle *randomly*, but right now I get an undesired cluster around the center.

I saw a [similar SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29061145/6105259), but it's in c# and I don't understand how to adapt it to `R` code.

### My code so far

The following code defines a custom visualization function `vis_points_inside_circle()`, and then calls it 4 times to give 4 examples of visualizing using my current method.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

## set up function
vis_points_inside_circle <- function(n) {
  
  # part 1 -- set up empty circle
  df_empty_circle <-
    data.frame(x = 0,
               y = 0, 
               r = 1)
  
  p_empty_circle <-
    ggplot(df_empty_circle) +
    geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = r)) + 
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_void()
  
  # part 2 -- set up points scatter
  r <- runif(n)
  th <- runif(n)
  
  df_circular_points_scatter <- 
    data.frame(x = r*cos(2*pi*th),  ## from @Ben's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68606605/6105259
               y = r*sin(2*pi*th))
  
  
  # part 3 -- combine circle and points
  p_empty_circle +
    geom_point(data = df_circular_points_scatter, 
               aes(x = x, y = y))
}

## visualize
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(2021)
p1000_1 <- vis_points_inside_circle(n = 1000)
p1000_2 <- vis_points_inside_circle(n = 1000)
p2000_1 <- vis_points_inside_circle(n = 2000)
p2000_2 <- vis_points_inside_circle(n = 2000)


gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1000_1, p1000_2, p2000_1, p2000_2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

It should be easy to notice the cluster around the center of each circle. How can we randomly arrange the points within the circle, to avoid the cluster at the center?

**My attempt with `sample()`**

I guess the solution involves the modification of `df_circular_points_scatter` data. However, I don't know how. I've tried to wrap each of `df_circular_points_scatter`'s columns with `sample()`, but then got points that exceed the circumference, and overall a "cross" arrangement.

That is, if we wrap with `sample()` like this:

```r
r  <- runif(n)
th <- runif(n)

df_circular_points_scatter <- 
    data.frame(x = sample(r*cos(2*pi*th)),  
               y = sample(r*sin(2*pi*th)))
```

Then the result is:

[image: points_exceeding]

---

Any idea how to avoid clustering? I don't necessarily want a perfectly even scatter. Just random within the circle.

---

### Desired output

Adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29061071/6105259), the desired output should look something like:
[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. The sampling needs to be done as follows:

```r
r <- runif(n)
th <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)
  
df_circular_points_scatter <- 
 data.frame(x = sqrt(r) * cos(th), 
            y = sqrt(r) * sin(th)

)
```

(see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481543/generating-random-points-uniformly-on-a-disk) question on crossvalidated)

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have the points eventually distributed in r and theta, but you want them to be evenly distributed in *area*.

As the area element in the circle is $r dr dtheta$ (not $dr dtheta$ as your code implies), so you should transform
`r <- sqrt(r)`